# PHP - if isset shorthand

Tags: php

Quick question. I have seen in tutorials that simple if statement is written like this:

```
if($vest) echo $vest->naslov
```

But when I write it like that, I get an error  **Undefined variable: vest** and I have to write the code old fashion way:

```
if(isset($vest)) echo $vest->naslov
```

Are there any setting in the **php.ini** file that regulate this? At the moment I am using LAMP on Ubuntu (latest version).

Answer (score 4):

You have `E_STRICT` on, which complains if you don't have variables declared before checking them. You *could* fix this by turning off `E_STRICT` in `php.ini`, but a better idea would be to simply declare your variables ahead of time - just do this, at the top of your function:

```
$vest = null;
```

before the rest of your logic. This is good practice, because it forces you to think about the way your program executes in a way that more closely matches reality.

Answer (score 2):

You can lower `error_reporting` to `E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE`, but it's actually a bad practice which can lead to a lot of hard to track down bugs.  if `$vest` is a typo, you won't know, and your conditions will never work.

Instead, try to structure your application so you always know which variables are defined and which aren't.  Then, you *can* use the shorthand version without worry.

Answer (score 1):

`Undefined variable: vest` error mean that variable `$vest` is not recognized. The reason `isset($vest)` does not generate error is because `isset()` check whether `$vest` is already set, or not. Therefore if(isset($vest)) will do a boolean check to the return value of `isset($vest)`.

If you just use `if($vest)`, php will assume `$vest` is already set (when in fact, `$vest` is still undefined) and it do a boolean check operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn down the error reporting level and *ignore* the error, but that would be dangerous programming practice.

When you type this: `if($vest)`, do you really mean `$vest==null` or `$vest==''` or `$vest===''` or `isempty($vest)` or `$vest===true` or isset($vest)`?

There are a lot of uses for if statements; you should make it clear in your code what exactly you are doing.  Is it really so hard to initialize the variable at the top of your script?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's better practice to declare your variables to the negative state, then - if they are not set, or they are set to false then - the shorthand `if` will act as you intend.

Ignoring errors is bad (they are there for a reason, and your code will be more readable, therefore maintainable).

Comment: declaring them to null casts to false for the purposes of `if`. also, most other purposes.

Comment: I'd normally do `null`myself, but without knowing the context (i.e. later usage of the variable) they are using it in.. left it open for them.

Answer (score 1):

`if($foo)` and `if(isset($foo))` are not the same thing and shouldn't be used interchangeably.

`if($foo)` checks wheter or not `$foo` evaluates to true. Another way of writing that would be: `if( (bool) $foo === true )`. Therefore, if `$foo` is undefined, a notice from PHP is expected.

Rather than turning off notices, like some people suggested, write your code the correct way. To check if `$foo` is defined, always use `isset()`.